# Exchange 2016 Send As - multiple domain names

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-2016

Got a question regarding “Sending As” in Exchange 2016 and outlook 2010

Picture the scene

The company has a exchange server that hosts emails for multiple domains.  In this example they are *example.com* and *acme.com*

There is a user call *Paul* with a single exchange mailbox and he can receive emails as *paul@example.com* and *paul@acme.com*. When he sounds out it defaults to *paul@acme.com*

There is a second mailbox called *sales*, that *paul* has full mailbox rights and send as rights.

When he goes to send an email from sales it goes go as *sales@acme.com*.
However from time to time Paul wants to send emails out as *sales@example.com*

**Can this be done?**

As a temp solution I’ve created a dummy POP3 account on the PC so he can send out as sales@example.com.

Just wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dummy account option is what we have used for years.

The other option would be to create a shared mailbox for sales@example.com with Send As rights, then put a forwarder on that mailbox to the sales@acme.com shared mailbox. The only problem would be that Sent Items for items sent from sales@example.com would not be placed in the sent items of the sales@acme.com mailbox.